# Is there a way I can add users with phone number to firebase admin sdk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am building a react app with firebase backend.
I would like an administrator to be able to add users to the app using the Firebase admin sdk.
Usually I would do that using a cloud function like this:

```
return admin.auth().createUser({
  email: data.email,
  password: data.password,
  displayName: data.name,
  disabled: false
})
```

How can I achieve the same using just the phone number and not the email and or password?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Did you already try just creating a user with just a phone number in this call: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user? What happened when you dad that? was there an error message?

Comment: I have added a comment.Please check

Comment: @Sky Lurk If the below information was useful consider accepting :) Feel free to ask further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think phone auth support is not  available in Firebase Admin SDK directly.It does not  provide end user authentication methods in the Admin SDK.

As this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) mentioned by frank in the above comment,if you create with just phone number by excluding  email and password fields.you will get a warning,  **you are creating user with email without giving email and password fields that are filled with blank fields**.But this should not done as per best practices I have tried in the past and it worked but with a warning

phone auth support available in Firebase client SDKs. The [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object you get when you complete the phone number sign in contains the unique ID of the user. It also takes care of creating the user account in the Firebase project:

From this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#next-steps)

> "After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is
> created and linked to the credentials—that is, the username and
> password, phone number, or auth provider information—the user signed
> in with. This new account is stored as part of your Firebase project,
> and can be used to identify a user across every app in your project,
> regardless of how the user signs in."

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way I can create with email and password and allow them to sign in with phone number?

Comment: I don't think we can signin with phone number to the Admin SDK directly.However `signInWithPhoneNumber()` is available in Firebase client SDK. you can check this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)